# PHP Slimframework CORS

Tags: php, angular, cors, slim

I'm in a bit trouble with this CORS thing. Angular 4 is running on localhost:4200, while Slimframework is running on localhost:8080.

My front-end HTTP request:

```
....
createPartner(partner: Partner): Observable<Partner> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type' : 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this.regUrl, partner, options)
           .map((res: Response) => {
              return res.json();
           })
           .catch(this.handleError);
  }
....
```

My middleware:

```
....
$app->add(function($request, $response, $next) {
$route = $request->getAttribute("route");

$methods = [];

if (!empty($route)) {
    $pattern = $route->getPattern();

    foreach ($this->router->getRoutes() as $route) {
        if ($pattern === $route->getPattern()) {
            $methods = array_merge_recursive($methods, $route->getMethods());
        }
    }
} else {
    $methods[] = $request->getMethod();
}

$response = $next($request, $response);


return $response->withHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", implode(",", $methods));
});
```

I added `"determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware" => true,` to my settings array.

The browser's (chrome) console says:

*XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://lvh.me/api/partner. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.*

What did I do wrong, guys? :/

Edit:

Forgot the 8080 port of the backend URI, now that I added, the new error is:

```
OPTIONS http://lvh.me:8080/api/partner net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Comment: My php is little bit rusty but i guess you have to add `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *')`, not sure how to do that with your framework, maybe via that `$response->withHeader`

Comment: Yea, i was trying with `->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');` but nothing happens..

Comment: Can you dump all your headers that you are getting from middleware? Some copy/paste. Maybe your headers are rewritten with something that you do not see. Happened to me lot of times.

Comment: I'm using now only this middleware, but if you tell me how do I do that, I'll do it.

Comment: In your `return this.http.post(this.regUrl, partner, options)` is this `this.regUrl` some url that you are handling with middleware and expects response from  middleware?

Comment: Also why don't you try to use `jsonp` as part of your request to middlware on frontend if you are having trouble with this `cors` things?

Comment: regUrl is the complete backend endpoint that is handled by a controller, but it didn't work so after some searching I added the middleware to handle CORS things.

Btw my headers: http://i.imgur.com/rQy8IqY.png

From postman, it works pretty well.

Comment: Yea, if I can't solve it other way, I'll refactor my code to jsonp.

Comment: So, frontend that is running at `4200` is calling middlware that runs on `8080` port and then middlware is calling this `lvh.me:8080`? And your problem is from `4200` to `8080`? If yes can you access directly middlware route via browser and paste headers?

Comment: lvh.me :8080 means localhost:8080 :D
Here are the header infos from Postman:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
Cache-Control →no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Connection →close
Content-Type →application/json;charset=utf-8
Date →Sat, 08 Jul 2017 18:00:34 +0200
Expires →Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Host →localhost:8080
Pragma →no-cache
X-Powered-By →PHP/7.1.4

Comment: You did not answer,  your problem is from `4200` to `8080`? Forget postman. I need to see headers from your middlware route and not your backend route.

Comment: On what port is your middlware is running?

Comment: Yes, problem is from 4200 to 8080. I don't really get what you mean under 'middleware' port.

Comment: Is your frontend is trying to access backend (api) port `8080`? What is this "middlware" for then? Is you middlware running on `4200` as well or that is something you are just calling "middlware" on your `8080` backend api?

Comment: It's called middleware. It manipulates response object before actually sending them to frontend. And yea, its on 8080 api, not frontend.

Comment: so ajax request from `localhost:4200` to `localhost:8080` is failing because of cors? Can you access `localhost:8080/api/partner` directly via browsers and paste headers?

Comment: are you calling maybe `OPTIONS` before actual `.post` request?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/4j3bDa2e  <- there's my headers from browser

Comment: can you do `options request` via postman and check headers?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/3g7Jp6VK <-- options via postman

Comment: You see there is no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` in options headers. So add to your middlware "OPTIONS" as well. This `preflight request` is actually that options thingy I think.

Comment: If u check my original post, you can see that I'm allowing every single method that the frontend asks. :D

Comment: But your headers for OPTIONS says there is no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` and that is why your request is failing.

Comment: If this `pastebin.com/3g7Jp6VK ` is from your options there is no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` in it.

Comment: Yea, that's what my post is about. 'What am I doing wrong in my middleware?"

Comment: I would debug this by first removing `htaccess` and to see what is actually going on. Then I would do  for this `implode(",", $methods) ` `var_dump(implode(",", $methods))` to check if some methods are not there  like `OPTIONS`.

Comment: Mhm, it says that only POST is allowed. I hardcoded the OPTIONS into the $methods array, not it says that OPTIONS, POST is allowed, but the error message from frontend is still there.

Comment: let me know if you `hardcode ` resolved this. I am curious.

Comment: It didn't solve it.

Comment: paste headers again from options, put all of `GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT` into middware.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/M0v64G9q Hardcoded the POST and OPTIONS

Comment: And btw, changing the url from lvh.me to localhost produced the first error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/api/partner. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: can you do skype and share your screen, i want to help you because i am now pissed that you are struggling with this. Send me your skype name.

Comment: how can I pm you? :D

Comment: sorry what is pm? not sure what you mean.

Comment: you can delete this comment with skype name now.

Comment: resolved by adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` to Slim framework middlware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved via skype by adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` to Slim framework middlware.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your htaccess to allow cors,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"

  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Content-Type"


  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteBase /

</IfModule>
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/maxparm/3105526

Comment: I tried these kind of simple solutions too, but didn't work.

Comment: This answer is only applicable if he is using Apache.

Comment: My .htaccess: `RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"

  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Content-Type"



</IfModule>`

And im still getting the error.